# Problems with html forms

Tags: html

My form views fine in IE7 and IE8 but FireFox does not display the form correctly:  The problem is it does not display the form inside my "mainContent1"

Note my code below:

```
<div id="mainContent1">
<form action="forms.php" target="_self">
<fieldset>
<legend>Postal Address</legend>  
<label for="street">Street address:</label>
<input id="street" name="street" type="text" />
<label for=" suburb">County</label>
<input id="county" name="county" type="text" />
<label for="state">State</label>
<input id="state" name="state" type="text" />
<label for="zip">Zip Code</label>
<input id="zip" name="zip" type="text" />
</fieldset>
</form>
</div>


fieldset {      
float: left;      
clear: both;      
width: 100%;      
margin: 0 0 -1em 0;      
padding: 0 0 1em 0;      
border-style: none;      
border-top: 1px solid #BFBAB0;      
background-color: #F2EFE9;    
}

legend {  
margin-left: 1em;  
color: #000000;  
font-weight: bold;  
}  

fieldset ol {  
padding: 1em 1em 0 1em;  
list-style: none;  
}  

fieldset li {  
padding-bottom: 1em;  
} 

fieldset.submit {  
border-style: none;  
}

label em {        
display: block;        
color: #060;        
font-size: 85%;        
font-style: normal;        
text-transform: uppercase;      
}
```

Comment: markup looks valid, can you maybe post any related CSS rules?

Comment: Are you floating the form using css?

Comment: I tested your sample code with bare minimum xhtml page and it does display correctly on Opera, Firefox and Safari. So the problem has to be somewhere else on your page, or in the CSS definitions

Comment: The only thing I see that is wrong here is the for-attribute for the country-input. It says " suburb" but there is no input field with that id. Can you please describe the problem with your code in detail?

Comment: This is my css.  The error occurs when I use the <fieldset> and I agree it has to be in my css.
    fieldset {      
    float: left;      
    clear: both;      
    width: 100%;      
    margin: 0 0 -1em 0;      
    padding: 0 0 1em 0;      
    border-style: none;      
    border-top: 1px solid #BFBAB0;      
    background-color: #F2EFE9;    
    }
    legend {  
    margin-left: 1em;  
    color: #000000;  
    font-weight: bold;  
    }  
    fieldset ol {  
    padding: 1em 1em 0 1em;  
    list-style: none;  
    }  
    fieldset li {  
    padding-bottom: 1em;  
    }

Comment: @Stefan ah, I missed that, good catch...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting a clearing div at the bottom, inside of #mainContent1...

```
<div id="mainContent1">
<form action="forms.php" target="_self">
<fieldset>
<legend>Postal Address</legend>  
<label for="street">Street address:</label>
<input id="street" name="street" type="text" />
<label for=" suburb">County</label>
<input id="county" name="county" type="text" />
<label for="state">State</label>
<input id="state" name="state" type="text" />
<label for="zip">Zip Code</label>
<input id="zip" name="zip" type="text" />
</fieldset>
</form>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a clearing div, it is cleaner to use the ".clearfix" method of clearing.

```
.clearfix:after{content:".";display:block;clear:both;height:0;visibility:hidden}
```

However, for IE you will need to add this to your IE css file:

```
.clearfix{zoom:1}
```

Then you simply add the class to the container element to clear the floats correctly.

```
<div id="mainContent1" class="clearfix">
<form action="forms.php" target="_self">
<fieldset>
<legend>Postal Address</legend>  
<label for="street">Street address:</label>
<input id="street" name="street" type="text" />
<label for=" suburb">County</label>
<input id="county" name="county" type="text" />
<label for="state">State</label>
<input id="state" name="state" type="text" />
<label for="zip">Zip Code</label>
<input id="zip" name="zip" type="text" />
</fieldset>
</form>
</div>
```

This removes the need for extra empty elements within your HTML.